# How can I setup 3 monitors so that 2 & 3 are mirrored?

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have an nVidia GeForce GT 730 & am using the nVidia proprietary driver (361.42) on Ubuntu 16.04. I have 2 monitors & a projector. The first monitor maxes out at 1280x1024. The second monitor & the projector are both capable of 1920x1080 max resolution.

I want to have the 1st monitor set as the primary with the 2nd monitor & the projector mirrored at 1920x1080. I have tried the solution here ([How can I mirror one of the screens in a 3-monitor setup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576870/how-can-i-mirror-one-of-the-screens-in-a-3-monitor-setup)) but it doesn't work. I get the 1st screen working, but the 2nd & projector both go blank.

I have also tried a splitter cable, but then I cannot set the resolution to anything sane; the settings max out way below 1920x1080 & the Display window cannot properly detect the display(s) but shows "Unknown display".

It is possible to get the setup I am after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to solve this via software but I did find hardware that made everything work as desired. I purchased a video splitter box (this one for reference - [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01CZAJUCG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CZAJUCG)) & it has solved my problem. Apparently a splitter cable just confuses the computer as to which display identification to believe where a video splitter box only sends one display's EDID to the graphics card. And provided you select a resolution that is supported by both displays, everything should work.