# How to enable mirrored displays on Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 17.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 and I'm not sure how to enable mirrored displays (i.e. all displays show the same thing) since the UI has changed.

Tried following [the steps in the official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html) which mention a "Mirror" option in "the list of monitor configuration".

I'm unable to find such an option. This is what my Displays config looks like:

[image: Screenshot of Displays control panel]

Answer (score 1):

You should have some extra options at the top of the screen , not shown in your screen shot.

See this screenshot which shows the display mode at the top.

[image]

You need to select "Join Displays" - circled in red.  That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Interesting! Why's that not showing for me? Could I be missing a package?

Comment: This menu does not show up if you connect 2 or more external displays.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer here: [How can I mirror one of the screens in a 3-monitor setup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576870/how-can-i-mirror-one-of-the-screens-in-a-3-monitor-setup)

A quick fix (though not perfect when two displays have different resolution) is: Type

```
>> xrandr
```

It'll show you all the displays and possible resolution supported. From this output, and display menu, figure out name of the two displays. For me it was: LVDS-1 (built in) and VGA-1 (display I have attached). Then as suggested in the above link simply use command:

```
>> xrandr --output LVDS-1 --output VGA-1 --same-as LVDS-1
```

(you need to change LVDS-1 and VGA-1 appropriately, as mentioned above).

That's it, now two displays are mirrored. cheers